# Geração de boletos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá,

Preciso gerar boletos em uma aplicação. Nunca trabalhei com geração de boletos. Alguém poderia me explicar por onde começar, quais são os primeiros passos, o caminho das pedras?

Eu dei uma pesquisa e vi que existe um componente Boleto .Net que parece que é bastante usado e também tem o CobreBem, que pelo o que me parece é pago.

Gostaria de exemplos e de documentação de um deles, bem como entender os termos usados dentro da documentação e como obter as informações da conta.

Obrigado.

Comment: Da uma lida em [**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](/help/mcve), caso já tenha feito algo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## O Caminho das Pedras

[Aqui está um projeto de exemplo](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/tree/master/src/Boleto.Net.MVC). Basta fazer o download do zip ou clonar o repositório e testar. Não tem muito segredo.

Para instalar no seu projeto, [utilize o pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Boleto.Net/).

[Aqui tem um exemplo passo a passo de como fazer](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/blob/master/src/Boleto.Net.MVC/Models/Exemplos.cs). Particularmente não acho que esta implementação esteja 100%, mas é um bom começo.

Normalmente os bancos cedem manuais e informações de como implementar. Ou ainda você [pode procurar o banco que vai usar nesta lista](http://boletonet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Documenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o&referringTitle=Home). As informações relativas a conta, carteira, contrato e afins são fornecidas pelo(a) gerente da conta. Normalmente a conta tem que ser jurídica. Nunca vi geração de boleto pra pessoa física.

Sobre o campo "Nosso Número", é um campo que você pode usar para identificar uma compra no seu sistema, portanto, é um campo que você define.

Grosso modo, é isso que você precisa pra começar. No mais, acho que vale a pena abrir perguntas mais específicas.